com.ibm.icu plugin conflict in Eclipse Kepler after upgrading
I am developing a desktop application based on Eclipse Kepler plugins. Initially, I used Kepler 4.3.2 (2014) with JDK 1.8.0_231. Later, I use  Kepler 4.33 (2024)and JDK 17. During this upgrade, I encountered a plugin version conflict.
Kepler 4.33 uses com.ibm.icu_76.1.0.jar, while the old version relied on com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar. These two versions are incompatible.
If I replace com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130 with com.ibm.icu_76.1.0, the application can run in Eclipse. However, I face an error when setting the target platform:
Problems occurred while resolving the target contents: File does not exist: ... com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.
File does not exist: ....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.bundle_pool\plugins\com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar.
If I replace com.ibm.icu_76.1.0 with com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130, the IDE(Kepler 2024) cannot started.
On the other hand, if I do not replace com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130 with com.ibm.icu_76.1.0, I cannot add the required plugins, and the application fails to run because there are 2 versions of com.ibm.icu.
Here is the CAR.target file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="CAR" sequenceNumber="46">
<locations>
<location path="${eclipse_home}" type="Directory"/>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.cvs.source.feature.group" version="1.4.100.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.test.feature.group" version="3.6.101.v20150202-1306"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.releng.tools.feature.group" version="3.5.1.v20140604-1105"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cvs.feature.group" version="1.4.100.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.4.2.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ee.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.1.v20140424-1723"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.10.2.v20150204-1316"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.4.2.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.source.feature.group" version="3.10.1.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.tests.feature.group" version="4.4.1.v20150204-2305"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.plugins.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.0.v20140416-1648"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="3.10.1.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.examples.source.feature.group" version="3.5.401.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="3.10.1.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="3.10.1.v20150204-1700"/>
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>

After updating the CAR.target file by changing the repository path and version of units:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="CAR" sequenceNumber="46">
<locations>
<location path="${eclipse_home}" type="Directory"/>
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.cvs.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.test.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.releng.tools.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cvs.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ee.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.tests.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.plugins.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.examples.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.33/"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>

I got other errors:
problem loading repositories

There is no such thing as "Kepler 2024" release. Eclipse Kepler was the name of the 4.3 release of the Eclipse IDE from 2013/4. There are 4 releases of the Eclipse IDE in 2024 called 2024-03, 2024-06, 2024-09 and 2024-12. From the icu version it seems that you are using Eclipse 2024-12 (4.34)

It sounds like you need to update your target platform to specifiy the new version of icu

Thank you for your suggestion!
However, how can I update the target platform properly?
I’ve removed com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar from all locations and replaced it with the new version. Despite this, when I reload the target platform, I still encounter the error:
File does not exist: ... com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.

Are there conflicts with other related plugins?
Should I identify and update them as well?

Please include your target platform definition file in your question. Your question still tells "I upgraded to Kepler 2024", but as already said by greg-449, Eclipse Kepler was the name of the Eclipse simultaneous release more than ten years ago. Nowadays, the simultaneous releases are named with a date of the year and month of the release: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases It is unclear from where to where you upgraded and which error message you get exactly for which action.

"The new Kepler uses..." - There is no new Kepler. Kepler was the name of a simultaneous release more than a decade ago. Your code should not refer com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130 at all (v201304230130 means it's from April 23, 2013). There are several ways to set the target platform. How did you set your target platform and what does your target platform look like? If you have a target platform definition file, please show it. If you don't have one, I would recommend to create one.

Thank you for your response.
My project already includes a .target and a .product file, as it was originally developed in Kepler 4.3.2 (2014).
After importing the project into Kepler 4.33 and upgrading the JDK to version 17, I encountered an error when attempting to set the target platform for my project:
"There are 2 versions of com.ibm.icu..."
This prevented me from adding the required plugins.

To address this, I replaced com.ibm.icu_76.1.0.jar in the plugins folder of Kepler 4.33 with com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar. However, after making this change, I could no longer start the IDE.
I reverted the com.ibm.icu file in the Kepler 4.33 plugins folder to version 76.1.0. Then, I replaced the com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar file in the workspace containing the project (.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.bundle_pool\plugins) with com.ibm.icu_76.1.0.jar.

With this approach, I was able to add the required plugins and run my application in Kepler 4.33. However, I still cannot set the target platform due to the following error:
File does not exist: ....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core.bundle_pool\plugins\com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar.
What should I do next?
Thank you for your support.

Please open your CAR.target file and in the Source tab copy all the XML and paste it into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). Your target platform definition file should refer public update sites (like e.g. here), but it seems to refer to a local installation that has been updated in the meantime.

I've added the CAR.target source file in the question.

The problem is the line <location path="${eclipse_home}" type="Directory"/> which includes everything of the Eclipse IDE you use and which will not work in a Maven/Tycho build. To migrate from Eclipse 4.3 to 4.33, change https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/ to https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.33/ and set all versions to 0.0.0 (similar to here).

After updating the CAR.target file, I got other errors related to loading repositories (more detailed in the question).
What should I need to do next to solve this problem?
